# How to add images to taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Could it be done or not?

E.g. I want to be ble to upload an image when creating a new taxnomy term.

So, when I create a new term called **Mercedes** in my custom made taxonomy called **brands** how can I add a file picker field to that term so I can upload an image of Mercedes logo?

Is it even possible to upload a file for taxonomy?

Comment: A [search on our site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=term%20image) will bring up many more solutions. Please, always search before you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was actually a plugin written for this a while back - http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/